# How to calculate total no of groups

Tags: combinations

How to calculate total no of arrangements of n+m objects into groups of any number?

For example, if we have 3 black balls and 1 white ball than all groups are-

$$(bbbw);(b,bbw);(bb,bw);(bbb,w);(b,bb,w);(b,b,bw);(b,b,b,w) $$

Hence here $7$ groups are possible

Comment: Probably shouldn't use the word "group" this way - it has a very specific meaning.

Comment: So you have $n$ identical black balls and $m$ identical white balls?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not easy.  Even computing the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ objects is not easy.  The number is given in [OEIS A000041](http://oeis.org/A000041) and begins $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30, 42$.  To figure it out for a given $n,m$ you can list the partitions of each.  For each pair of a partition of $n$ and a partition of $m$, you can extend the longer with one zero and the shorter with enough zeros to match the length of the longer (including the zero).  If that length is $k$ you have $k!$ ways to match up the partitions, but some of them will be duplicates because there are multiple parts of the same size.  In your example there are three partitions of $3$, which we express as $(3,0),(2,1,0),(1,1,1,0)$.  For a given length there is only one partition of $1$.  We get two alignments for the $(3,0)$ partition, three for the $(2,1,0)$ partition because of the duplicate zeros in $(1,0,0)$ and two for the $(1,1,1,0)$ giving the seven you found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still don't get it.  Is there any formula for this??